# remove child not working - child is reinstated if the node is referenced again

Tags: javascript

using :

```
var replaceElement = function replaceElement(el,replacement){
    console.debug(arguments);
    var par=el.parentNode,sibling=el.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(el);
    par.insertBefore(replacement,sibling);
};
```

The replacement is being inserted before the sibling (and 'el') but 'el' is not being removed from parent.

These nodes were created with innerHTML. Not too sure what else would be causing the problem.

Comment: Ok found the answer right after I posted the question but thought it was interesting enough if anybody wants to chime in:

After I removed the node, I referenced it again to retrieve data attached to it. After referencing it again, the node was placed back into the parent.

Comment: Glad you answer your own question.  I suggest that you update the query with the answer code for someone to see.  Also, why var replaceElement = function replaceElement?  Either var replaceElement = function(.... OR function replaceElement(....